# Does Laravel clone query reduce query time?

Tags: mysql, laravel

When I have to get `paid` and `pending` orders, I searched and found a way to clone the query.

```php
$paid = $products->clone()->where('paid', 1)->count();
$pending = $products->clone()->where('paid', 0)->count();
```

I wonder if this approach saves query time or if we still send two requests to the database server.

Thanks

Comment: What is `$query`? Is it a `Builder` object or a `Collection` resulting from a query? How are you using `$query` and `$queryGet` to obtain paid and pending orders? Depending on your approach, the amount of queries and performance may vary.

Comment: I assume `$products` is a query that has other conditions common to both queries?

Comment: if `$product` is a query builder instance and since before cloning no query is run (it runs when using `count()`) so technically no, it will not reduce query time, it will only save you the time of setting up the query builder instance, which is insignificant compared to the query time.

Comment: How should this reduce the number of queries if you filter by two different values?

Answer (score 0):

laravel added the `Illuminate\Support\Benchmark` utility class in version 9.32. If you have it available, you can test for yourself.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Benchmark;

public function yourControllerMethod()
{
    $products = Product::query();
    $iterations = 100;
    Benchmark::dd(
        [
            'cloning' => function () use ($products) {
                $products->clone()->where('paid', 1)->count();
                $products->clone()->where('paid', 0)->count();
            },
            'not cloning' => function () {
                Product::query()->where('paid', 1)->count();
                Product::query()->where('paid', 0)->count();
            },
        ],
        $iterations
    );
}
```

Both approaches will execute the same amount of SQL queries though. I think the time saved (if any) will be minimal.